# jQuery address plugin change parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, browser-history

I use Asual's jQuery address plugin. Currently I need to change the url parameter, and I do it this way:

```
// init state
$.address.state('/');

// change parameter
$.address.parameter('q', 'val');
```

I have the following url:
`http://example.com/admin/cities/`

and expect it to be changed this way:
`http://example.com/admin/cities/?q=val`

But it changes to this one:
`http://example.com/?q=val`

Ok, I think, let's set state this way:

```
$.address.state('/admin/cities/');
```

It starts working as I expect, BUT then I'm getting another problem. In the other place I need to set `$.address.value()` based on `href` (where I have absolute path):

```
$.address.value($(el).attr('href'));
```

Doing this I expect my url to be changed from `http://example.com/admin/cities/?q=val` to `http://example.com/what/i/have/in/href?some=param` but instead I'm getting `http://example.com/admin/cities/what/i/have/in/href?some=param`.

On the other hand, this problem doesn't exist if I first do

```
$.address.state('/');
$.address.value($(el).attr('href'))
```

and only then

```
$.address.parameter('q', 'val');
```

In this case, everything works properly. First of all `http://example.com/admin/cities/` changes to `http://example.com/what/i/have/in/href?some=param` and then the parameter is being added: `http://example.com/what/i/have/in/href?some=param&q=val`

That said, it seems like either I'm doing something incorrectly or the plugin has a bug with initialization.

Actually I found a solution for myself but to be a proper way. Here it is:

```
$.address.state('/');
// switching off auto update in order to avoid adding value to the browser history
$.address.autoUpdate(false);
$.address.value(document.location.pathname+document.location.search);
$.address.autoUpdate(true);
```

In this case the plugin becomes "initialized" and changing the parameter just changes/adds it without changing the path, and changing values also keeps working as well.

That said, my question is the following: is there a better way to solve my problem?

UPDATE:
In fact, I'm open to other solutions that utilize pushState()/replaceState().

Comment: Dunno if it helps with what you're doing, but I have a nice little jQuery plug myself for working with current URL. [Blog](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-myurl-extension-how-to-get-that.html) : [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SpYk3/2ZuTe/)

Comment: Oh, and not mentioned on the blog is a new feature i added to it to allow you to  set parameters based on dynamics. In other words, send as an array using the key terms `key` and `value`. Like so: `$.myURL("someDir", "someContent.xx", [{ key: 'keyName', value: 'a string value' }])`

Comment: @SpYk3HH, no, your plugin will not help. I need a solution that utilizes html5's pushState. You can read more information here: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: OIC, np, was just throwin it out there in case